# What is the shortest possible way to write a block scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope

Is this the shortest possible way to get a block scope in the body of the `for` loop?

```
x = {};
for (i of ['a', 'b']) {
  (function(i) {
    x[i] = function() { this.v = i; }
  })(i);
}
```

Or is there any syntactic sugar I am not able to find?

*Explanation:*

With block scope the created objects have different values.

`new x.a` ⟹ `x.(anonymous function) {v: "a"}`
`new x.b` ⟹ `x.(anonymous function) {v: "b"}`

Without block scope

```
y = {};
for (i of ['a', 'b']) {
  y[i] = function() { this.v = i; }
}
```

the created objects will have the same value.

`new y.a` ⟹ `y.(anonymous function) {v: "b"}`
`new y.b` ⟹ `y.(anonymous function) {v: "b"}`

Comment: Depends whether you're willing to use ES6 or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are using an ES6 `for of` loop, you already have block scope for your iteration variable anyway - just don't forget to use a `let`/`const` declaration! There is no need for an IEFE.

```
let x = {};
for (let i of ['a', 'b'])
    x[i] = function() { this.v = i; };
```

If you don't use ES6, I'd recommend to use one of the [`Array` iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods), like

```
var x = ['a', 'b'].map(function(i) {
    return function() { this.v = i; };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `let` exists nowadays. This explains it quite well: http://davidwalsh.name/for-and-against-let