# Making onClick delete function for multiple list items

Tags: javascript, function, sharepoint-online, office365api

I'm currently working on a custom commenting solution for SharePoint pages using the Rest API. I'm having trouble making delete buttons for each comment based on their id.

My Delete function looks like this and deletes list items based in id:

```
function deleteListItems(id) {
$.ajax  
    ({  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Comments')/items(" + id + ")",  
        type: "POST",  
        headers:  
    {  
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",       
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
        "IF-MATCH": "*",  
        "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"  
    },  
    success: function()  
    {  
        window.location.reload; 
    },  
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
    }  
});  
}
```

Each comment are created from an array of comment objects with distinct id's and for each of them i create a delete button from the following snippet:

```
for (var i = 0; i < commentObj.length; i++) {

    //Making of the comment contents

    var deleteBtn = document.createElement("a");
    btnContent = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    deleteBtn.appendChild(btnContent);
    deleteBtn.onclick = function(){deleteListItems(commentObj[i].Id)};
    newComment.appendChild(deleteBtn);
}
```

Now the issue is that all the delete buttons delete the last item in the array of comments instead of the comment it's attached too. Is there a way to "prime" the delete function for each button with the correct ID instead of just deleting the last item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript the keyword `var` defines a function variable. The `for` loop does not create a new scope for `i`. This means, when your function gets called, the value of `i` is the value after the loop as ended, which references the last item.

[Use `let` instead of `var`](https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6/).

Comment: My Company unfortunately uses an old version of IE so i can't use let or const, but i solved the problem by making a function that makes the delete function, and from that i made a variable and passed in the ID

Comment: BTW: I had the same problem some years ago: [What is the shortest possible way to write a block scope in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463505/what-is-the-shortest-possible-way-to-write-a-block-scope-in-javascript)